# Decompress RLE string recursively

Tags: java

I am getting this error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1920)
at StringRec.decompress(StringRec.java:18)
at StringRec.decompress(StringRec.java:19)
at StringRec.decompress(StringRec.java:19)
....
...."
```

when I input string q9w5e2rt5y4qw2Er3T into this code.

```
public static String decompress(String compressedText) {

    if(compressedText.length() <= 1){
        return compressedText;
    }
    else if(Character.isLetter(compressedText.charAt(0)) == true){
        return compressedText.charAt(0)+decompress(compressedText.substring(1));
    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(0)) == true){
        char c = compressedText.charAt(0);
        int a = c--;
        char b = (char) a;
        compressedText = b+compressedText.substring(1);
        return c+decompress(compressedText);
    }
    return compressedText.charAt(0)+decompress(compressedText.substring(1));

}
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Because for this assignment I have to decompress a string (assuming that the character counts will be single-digit numbers (a character will not repeat more than 9 times consecutively) recursively only, without using any loops.

Comment: `int a = c--;` when `c` is `0` will give you `47`.  Then `char b = (char) a;` will give you a `b` of `'/'`.  Since you're missing a pure `else` clause in your method, this puts you in an infinite loop (until you run out of stack, anyway).

Comment: Thank you, very helpful in finding my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there...  Here's the hint you need:

```
int val = Character.getNumericValue(compressedText.charAt(0))
```

Because I don't think these lines are doing what you intend:

```
char c = compressedText.charAt(0);
int a = c--;
char b = (char) a;
```